# Need advice on turning Java Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

So, the jest of it is, a version of an application at my company is having some memory issues lately, and I'm not fully sure the best way to fix it that isn't just "Allocate more memory", so I wanted to get some guidance.

For the application, It looks like the eden heap is getting full pretty quickly when it has a concurrent users, so objects that won't be alive very long end up in the old heap. After running for a while, the old heap simply gets fulls, and never seems to automatically clean up, but manually running the garbage collection in VisualVM will clear it out (So I assume this means the old heap is full of dead objects)

Is there any setting suggested I could add so garbage collection gets run on the old heap once it gets to a certain threshold? And is there any pitfalls from changing the old/edin ratio from the stock 2:1 to 1:1? For the application, the majority of objects created are what I would consider short lived (From milliseconds to a few minutes)

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve? I do see any problem statement in your description.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like the eden heap is getting full pretty quickly when it has a concurrent users, so objects that won't be alive very long end up in the old heap.

This is called "premature promotion"

> After running for a while, the old heap simply gets fulls,

When it fills, the GC triggers a major or even a full collection.

> never seems to automatically clean up

In which case, it is either used or it is not completely full. It might appear to be almost full, but the GC will be performed when it is actually full.

> but manually running the garbage collection in VisualVM will clear it out

So the old gen wasn't almost but not actually full.

> I could add so garbage collection gets run on the old heap once it gets to a certain threshold?

You can run System.gc() but this means more work for you application and slow it down.  You don't want to be doing this.

If you use the CMS collector you can change the threshold at which it kicks in but unless you need low latency you might be better off leaving your settings as they are.

> And is there any pitfalls from changing the old/edin ratio from the stock 2:1 to 1:1?

You reduce the old gen, you you may half the number of GCs you perform and double the amount of time an object can live and not end up in the old gen.

I work in the low latency space and usually set the young space to 24 GB and the old gen to 2 GB.  I also use a lot of off heap data so I don't need much old gen.  This is not an average use case, but it can work depending on your requirements.

If you are using < 32 GB, just adding a few more GB may be the simplest answer.  Also you can use something like `-Xmn4g -Xms6g` to set the young space and maximum heap not worry about ratios.

> For the application, the majority of objects created are what I would consider short lived (From milliseconds to a few minutes)

In that case, ideally you want your eden space large enough so you have a minor collection every few minutes.  This way most of your objects will die in the eden space, and not be copied around.

Note: in extreme cases it is possible to have an application produce less than one GB per hour of garbage and run all day with a 24 GB Eden space without even a minor collection.